# Manipulating the preimage

Tags: real-analysis

For part b) I do not understand the section of the solution underlined in orange. I could understand this if $f^{-1}$  were an inverse due to it then being a bijection but here $f^{-1}$  means the preimage.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The part in orange follows from the following elementary result. Suppose $f : X \to Y $ is a function and $B \subset Y $, then

$$ f^{-1}( Y \setminus B) = Y \setminus f^{-1}(B)$$

In your case, put $Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $B = A $

Comment: Why can't an $\in f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)=$ an $ \in f^{-1}(A)$?